# Setting color theme and special characters

Tags: beamer, color, languages

I'm pretty comfortable with LaTeX, but today I began to use the Beamer class and I'm finding some difficulties just right at the begining. So... I got two questions. But first I'll show you guys my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\usecolortheme{structure}
\title[Apresentação]{Projecto \\ Física Computacional}
\author{Ana Silva}
\institute{IST}
\date{22 de Janeiro, 2015}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Initial Data}
Something...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It's small, so I guess the errors are easy to identify. But I just don't get it...

So, first, when I compile it the way I pasted it here I get the error:

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `beamer@structure@color'.
```

I know that something's wrong when I set color theme. Do I have to use another package or something?

Then, when I suppress that color theme line I see that the special characters (like the í in "Física") just don't appear, even though I put the portuges package.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: For the special characters, add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to give the proper options (ie  color to be used for structural elements) to `\usecolortheme[<options>]{structure}`

For example, from the manual, if you use `\usecolortheme[named=SeaGreen]{structure}`

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\usecolortheme[named=SeaGreen]{structure}
\title[Apresentação]{Projecto \\ Física Computacional}
\author{Ana Silva}
\institute{IST}
\date{22 de Janeiro, 2015}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Initial Data}
Something...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You need to add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

additionally to get special characters properly.

Here is a snap shot from beamer user maual page 175 for reference:

[image]

Comment: Oh... I'll give a look to the user guide, then
Thanks!!

Comment: Any thoughts on the special characters, btw ?

Comment: @AnaSilva you need to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: Oh! Many thanks!!! \o/
(I should have noticed that!)

Comment: @AnaSilva: Glad it helped. Please don't forget to upvote and accept answer if it solved your problem. Refer [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) for details.

Comment: Exactly what I need. It helped a lot